# Typescript: How to manage dependencies with conflicting type declarations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, jestjs, testcafe

I have the error: `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type`

This is occurring because two of my dependencies, both of which I need; declare the same type.

**Jest** :`/node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts` => `declare var test: jest.`

**testcafe** `node_modules/testcafe//ts-defs/index.d.ts` => `declare var test: TestFn;`

My project is a react/redux project using webpack, babel and obviously Typescript.

The error occurs when I am running my dev server via `npm start` which uses `webpack-dev-server`. It also creates a problem when I run `jest` since it uses testcafe's version of the declared `Test` type.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Two libraries are claiming to own the same global variable - which will actually be the case at run-time?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh this occurs when I am running my dev server via `npm start ` which uses `webpack-dev-server`. It also creates a problem when I run `jest` since it uses `testcafe`'s version of Test type.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh  Neither when I run `npm start` which is running `webpack-dev-server` since jest nor testcafe are being executed. I think what is happening is typescript is checking all index.d.ts files associated with the project regardless if they are being used or not

Comment: @micahblu have you managed to find a solution after all this time ?

Comment: @TOPKAT not really, though I'm sure there is one. I haven't worked on a typescript codebase in some time now.

Answer (score 2):

Per discussion here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1537

You can exclude the end to end test files that TestCafe looks for in your local `tsconfig.json` file.

It's a hack but it worked for me.

Example `tsconfig.json` file, assuming all your end to end test modules are under `test/e2e`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test/e2e"
  ]
}
```